# Angularjs/Ionic TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

codes:
js:

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('GetMainMenu',['$http','$q','$cacheFactory',function($http,$q,$cacheFactory) {
            var methodStr = 'JSONP';
            var urlStr = 'http://localhost/bd/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
            var ptStr = {action:'bd_get_main_menus',callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'};

            return {
                getMainMenuItems: function(){
                    var deferred = $q.defer();

                  $http.jsonp(urlStr,{params: ptStr})
                        .success(function (data, status) {

                            deferred.resolve(data);

                            return deferred.promise;
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status) {

                            deferred.reject(data);

                            return deferred.promise;

                        });
                }
            }

        }])

angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http,GetMainMenu) {
    GetMainMenu.getMainMenuItems().then(
      function(data){
        $scope.mainMenus = data;
      });
});
```

run result:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>        at new  (ht.../www/js/controllers.js:42:33)
>        at invoke (ht.../www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11994:17)...

where is wrong in these codes?

Comment: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" Your GetMainMenu.getMainMenuItems() is undefined, and it supposed to be promise object to call method then().  Format your code.

Comment: Don't use the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to return `deferred.promise` from the getMainMenuItems function instead of in the callback functions used for `$http.jsonp`. This is because `getMainMenuItems` needs to return a promise.

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('GetMainMenu',['$http','$q','$cacheFactory',function($http,$q,$cacheFactory) {
    var methodStr = 'JSONP';
    var urlStr = 'http://localhost/bd/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    var ptStr = {action:'bd_get_main_menus',callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'};

    return {
        getMainMenuItems: function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

          $http.jsonp(urlStr,{params: ptStr})
                .success(function (data, status) {

                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (data, status) {

                    deferred.reject(data);
                });

           return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}])
```

Another alternative is to instead just return the promise from `$http.jsonp`:

```
return {
        getMainMenuItems: function(){
           return $http.jsonp(urlStr,{params: ptStr});
        };
```

Comment: @Bergi The deferred anti pattern can be avoided by using the alternative suggested above. I agree that it's best to avoid the deferred anti pattern.

Answer (score 4):

You should return the promise object outside the $http.
You can also return the $http because is a promise, is not necessary to have another promise.

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('GetMainMenu', ['$http', '$q', '$cacheFactory', function ($http, $q, $cacheFactory) {
    var methodStr = 'JSONP';
    var urlStr = 'http://localhost/bd/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    var ptStr = {action: 'bd_get_main_menus', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'};

    return {
      getMainMenuItems: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.jsonp(urlStr, {params: ptStr})
          .success(function (data, status) {

            deferred.resolve(data);
          })
          .error(function (data, status) {

            deferred.reject(data);
          });
      return deferred.promise
      }
    }

  }])

angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http, GetMainMenu) {
    GetMainMenu.getMainMenuItems().then(
      function (data) {
        $scope.mainMenus = data;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Yes, please don't use the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!