# AngularJS: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

First, I'm new in Angular. I prepare some Web Api and I want get some data from them. 
my service function get date (works fine):

```
var _getRole = function () {
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/User/CurrentUserRoles').then(function (results) {
        return results;
    });
};
```

and controller:

```
var role = [];
authService.getRole().then(function (results) {
     role = results.data;...
```

In this function in controller I get exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at n.$scope.login (http://localhost/.../app/controllers/loginController.js:27:30)
at ib.functionCall (http://localhost/.../Scripts/angular.min.js:199:303)
at Ec.(anonymous function).compile.d.on.f (http://localhost/.../Scripts/angular.min.js:216:74)
at n.$get.n.$eval (http://localhost/.../Scripts/angular.min.js:126:15)
at n.$get.n.$apply (http://localhost/.../Scripts/angular.min.js:126:241)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/.../Scripts/angular.min.js:216:126)
at HTMLButtonElement.c (http://localhost/.../Scripts/angular.min.js:32:389)
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: have you injected `$http` ?

Comment: is service - of course, in controller - no

Comment: ok, now - you are not returning the promise from `_getRole`

Comment: I inject and that doesn't help - anything change.

Comment: I've got something like this before:
var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(results);
            return deferred.promise;
anythink change - exception still there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs/Ionic TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209744/angularjs-ionic-typeerror-cannot-read-property-then-of-undefined)

Comment: @c69 duplicate answer is telling to create custom promise & returning that custom promise..I would not prefer that way...you could look at my answer..that is reusing promise return by `$http`

Comment: Yes, just adding return is enough. But that's stated in the last part of the accepted answer to the linked question.

Comment: `.then(function (results) { return results; });` looks totally superfluous? Remove it.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for edit, it was really of no meaning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return promise from function that `$http` does return itself.

**Code**

```
var _getRole = function () {
    return $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/User/CurrentUserRoles');
};
```